# pexpect Prompt with new line

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pexpect

I am automating application configuration on the CentOS with pexpect. My prompt is new line as below,

```
Please enter command below.
```

On the Next line (which is blank/new line line), i need to enter necessary commands,

i tried couple of things to match `r'\b below.\b'` to check for the new line `r'\r\n(\w+)'` , white space `(\s)` and so on but none of them is matching the `expect` prompt.

eg.

```
child.sendline('a')
child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT,r'\b below.\b'])
print child.before
```

it would be great help if any one can provide any suggestion for this ..

Comment: Try `r'.*\b below\.\b'` with `expect`

Comment: Or `.expect(r'Please enter command below\.\r\n')`

Comment: `pexpect` reads a stream and cannot check a *sequence* of characters, you are bound to use `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is old, but it may help someone)

This works for me with pxssh, which is basically a wrapper around this:

```
expect_string = 'below.'
child.expect(expect_string)
child.sendline('a')
print(child.before)
```

If I'm reading your code right, you have your sendline before you expect. You need to switch that.